# xcode6 storyboard uibutton image title laybout

Tags: uibutton, storyboard, uiedgeinsets

how can i set button's image and title correctly position.

now the storyboard preview like:
 [image: storyboard]

I add title and image to the button and set title and image edgeinset to get picture layout. but the button'size is changed with the phone size. so i can't set it in storyboard properly for all size.

i want to to know is there a way to deal with this situation?

thanks!

Comment: I can't see the screenshot.

Comment: still not visible check your end once

Comment: @Spynet sorry for my mistake, fixed it.

Comment: did u fixed the issue or not ?

Comment: @Spynet, up is about the screenshot invisieble issue

Answer (score 0):

see the tutorial link below ,

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

it's show how to fix constant heigh and width of view.

[image: here sreenshot]

you see clear in image how it done.

Comment: Link is not an answer.

Comment: Thank your reply, i don't think the link can resolve my problem. maybe i can add a label and a image view to replace button's image and title, and then add constraint on the label and imageview to get right answer. but i want to set button's edgeinset to resolve it.